# Error message in PhantomJS

Tags: r, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to extract the price tables of various commodities for specific dates from Investing.com, using Selenium and PhantomJS in R. Heres my PhantomJS script, used to extract silver prices. I keep getting errors on it, especially when I try to add the lines that click on buttons and sets dates. Does anyone have a quick fix? (I am trying to bypass CasperJS)

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'website.html'

page.open('https://www.investing.com/commodities/silver-historical-data', function (status) {

    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("datePickerIconWrap").click();
            document.getElementById("startDate").value = "09/01/2017";
            document.getElementById("endDate").value = "11/01/2017";
            document.getElementById("applyBtn").click();
        });

  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path,content,'w')
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't click on

```
document.getElementById("datePickerIconWrap").click();
```

But click on this instead:

```
document.getElementById("widgetFieldDateRange").click();
```

And then setting the values should work just fine, like this

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById("widgetFieldDateRange").click();
    document.getElementById("startDate").value = "09/01/2017";
    document.getElementById("endDate").value = "11/01/2017";
    document.getElementById("applyBtn").click();
});
```

Comment: So the error message is gone, but the table doesn't get loaded, any advice?

Comment: Does it open the date selector?

Comment: Just observered that the dates do not change neither

Comment: Just tried a couple of things, I'm able to update all date fields, but when I click on `#applyBtn` nothing happens.